# Host configuration in server.xml doesn't work in tomcat 8.0.33

Tags: tomcat, virtualhost, server.xml

Our host configuration in server.xml works well in Tomcat 7.0.62 but not in 8.0.33.

```
<Host name="www.projet-okinawa.ch" appBase="/okinawa/web/apache-tomcat-x.y.z/webapps/okinawa">
  <Context path="" docBase="."/>
</Host>
```

This allow us to access the web site by using the url http://www.projet-okinawa.ch that is redirected to https://www.projet-okinawa.ch:8443.

With 8.0.33 version that doesn't work, we got an http 404 error.
Any idea what the problem is ? What the difference is ?

Comment: Have you checked this [migration guide](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html) ?

Comment: I didn't but checked it now carefully and didn't notice anything conflicting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the follow way, it's working...

```
    <Host name="mysite.it"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Alias>www.mysite.it</Alias>

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="mysite_access_log" suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
        <Context path="" docBase="/opt/tomcat/webapps/MySite" reloadable="true"/>
    </Host>
```